# Average in Javascript by a key

Tags: javascript

i have an array:

```
{ year: 1921, rate: 8.3 },
  { year: 1925, rate: 8.2 },
  { year: 1926, rate: 8.2 },
  { year: 1927, rate: 8.2 },
  { year: 1927, rate: 8.3 },
```

i want it to look like:

```
{ year: 1921, rate: 8.3 },
  { year: 1925, rate: 8.2 },
  { year: 1926, rate: 8.2 },
  { year: 1927, rate: 8.25 }, >>>> average out ratings in 1927
```

what should I use to say that average out ratings for the years and create a new array with year and an average rating

Comment: You should describe your algorithm of calculating the average rating. And from 
`i want it to look like ...`, do you want to remove the duplicated `year 1927` from the original array?  I know your input, but there are tons of ways to get the output as you need. You did not say which way you want.

Comment: Its not about removing duplicates. What i want is an average of ratings in 1927. I just edited by data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to reduce to a array with the values.
To group the rates by the year.

Then map it back to an array of objects with calculated averages per year.

**Example snippet:**

```js
let arr = [{ year: 1921, rate: 8.3 }, { year: 1925, rate: 8.2 }, { year: 1926, rate: 8.2 }, { year: 1927, rate: 8.2 }, { year: 1927, rate: 8.3 }];

let result = Object.entries(arr
 .reduce((acc, x) => {
   let arr = acc[x.year] || [];
   arr.push(x.rate);
   acc[x.year] = arr;
   return acc;
 }, {}))
 .map((x)=> { 
    let year = x[0];
    let rates = x[1];
    let sum = rates.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    let avg = (sum / rates.length) || 0; 
    return { "year": year, "rate": avg };
 });
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit convoluted, but you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) to accomplish this in several steps.

- We use `chain` to tell lodash we want to chain several operations together.
- The first operation will be a `groupBy` on year.
- Next we `map` the results back to an object, with a key and rate.

  - the key is easy enough, we're just mapping through the groupBy key.
  - the rate we need to use a nested `reduce` to sum all the rates
  - then we divide the sum by the array length to get the average.

```js
var orig = [{ year: 1921, rate: 8.3 },
  { year: 1925, rate: 8.2 },
  { year: 1926, rate: 8.2 },
  { year: 1927, rate: 8.2 },
  { year: 1927, rate: 8.3 }];
  
 var grp = _.chain(orig)
   .groupBy('year')
   .map((v,k)=> ({
     key:k, 
     rate: _.reduce(v, (a,b) => a+b.rate, 0)/v.length
   }));
 
 console.log(grp);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

of course there are other ways to do this using vanilla JavaScript, but why reinvent the wheel when lodash already has `groupBy`?

Answer (score 0):

First filter the array then reduce and store the result in new array and search in the new array before doing the above tasks in the iteration.
This is the Naive way and not clean but answers your question you can optimize from here

```js
let a = [{ year: 1921, rate: 8.3 },
  { year: 1925, rate: 8.2 },
  { year: 1926, rate: 8.2 },
  { year: 1927, rate: 8.2 },
  { year: 1927, rate: 8.3 }]
  
let b = [];

for(let i =0;i<a.length;i++){
  const {year} = a[i];
    if(b.filter(ele=>ele.year === year).length){
      break;
    }else{
      const filteredArr = a.filter(ele=>ele['year'] === year)
      const avg = filteredArr.reduce((curr,acc)=>curr+acc['rate'],0);
      b.push({year,rate:avg/filteredArr.length})
    }
}
  
console.log(b);
```